# Difference of value of **(ptr+1) in char and int

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, initialization

Please help me out as to why in below code outputs are different:

```
int z[][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
printf("\n**(z+1): %d", **(z + 1));
```

Output: `(z+1): 4`

```
char y[][3] = { "A", "F", "G", "J", "M", "P" };
printf("\n**(y+1): %c", **(y+1));
```

Output: `(y+1): F`

Why in the above two outputs, first is checking the 4th index while in second output prints 2nd index ?

Comment: Can you compile with more warnings turned on? There may be undefined behaviour here from the way you're initializing these things. You're declaring a multi-dimensional array but initializing it with a 1D array. I'm not sure it can map that out properly given the ambiguous first level size. Is that `z[6][3]`?

Comment: Also, `**(z+1)` is not how you address this. Instead use `z[1][0]` or something readable.

Comment: Your initializers are misleading.  You should group them into sets of 3 values, e.g. `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`, which is how they're being used..

Comment: Remember that `"A"` is actually *two characters*, it's `"A\x00"` internally. Both of these are accessing the 4th element, which in the second case is the 4th character, or `F`. I bet you'd get wildly different results with `char y[][3] = { 'A', 'F', ... }`, or `J` as in the first example.

Comment: @tadman Good point. My comment said "initializers", but it really only applies to the first initializer, which initializes `z`.  The initializer for `y` is initializing 6 top-level array elements, each of which is a 3-character array that's intialized to a single character followed by a null character.  I believe the third character is implicitly initialized to the null character as well, at least for a static array.  Not sure if that's true for an automatic array.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, if there is an initializer with less values than required, the remaining elements will be filled with 0 also for automatic variables.

Comment: @tadman To initialize a 2D array with an 1D is not UB (at least not in C): "If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates or unions, these rulesapply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching rightbrace initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the contained union. **Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or ...**"

Comment: "**the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize the nextelement or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part**. (C18, 6.7.9/20)" - What I have sorrow about is "If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an **explicit** initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its initializer list. (C18, 6.7.9/22)" - It says "explicit" initializer. Here no "*explicit*" initializer is provided.

Comment: Sorry typo/thinko. Meant of course "To initialize a 2D array with *an initializer for a 1D array* is not UB (at least not in C)".

Comment: @tadman Since the first dimension of array is not defined here, it will automatically take that as 2 so finally, it will read like: z[][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; --> z[2][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };  --> z[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6 }};

Comment: Would adding a dimension be asking too much? Would specifying it in the nested form for clarity take too much work? Try and make your code obvious, not mysterious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why in the above two outputs, first is checking the 4th index while in second output prints 2nd index ?

That's not actually close to describing what is happening.

To understand what is happening, write the examples into their actual meaning

```
int z[][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
printf("\n**(z+1): %d", **(z + 1));
```

is actually

```
int z[][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
printf("\n**(z+1): %d", **(z + 1));
```

where `z[0]` is an array of three elements initialised with `{1, 2, 3}`  and `z[1]` is an array of three elements initialised with `{4,5,6}`.

In this `z + 1` is equal to `&z[0] + 1` which is equal to `&z[1]`  (the address of an array of three `int`).   So `*(z+1)` is (a reference to) `z[1]`  (an array of three elements) and `**(z+1)` is `z[1][0]`.   Since `z[1]` is an array initialised as elements `{4,5,6}`,  `z[1][0]` is the first element of that array.  This has a value of `4`.

In comparison,

```
char y[][3] = { "A", "F", "G", "J", "M", "P" };
printf("\n**(y+1): %c", **(y+1));
```

each of the string literals is initialised as an array of two elements e.g. `"A"` is initialised as `{'A', '\0'}`.

Now `y` is an array of arrays of three `char`.   If an array of three elements is given an initialiser with two `char`, as is the case here, the values that are not explicitly initialialised are zero-initialised.   So

```
char y[][3] = { "A", "F", "G", "J", "M", "P" };
```

is equivalent to

```
char y[][3] = { {'A', '\0', '\0'}, {'F', '\0', '\0'}, {'G', '\0', '\0'}, {'J', '\0', '\0'}, {'M', '\0', '\0'}, {'P', '\0', '\0'}};
```

So `y` is array of six elements, each of which is an array of three `char`.

Using the same logic as in the discussion of `z` above,  `y + 1` is equal to `&y[1]` where `y[1]` is an array of three `char` that is initialized as `{'F', '\0', '\0'}`.
So `*(y + 1)` is (a reference to) `y[1]`, and `**(y + 1)` is `y[1][0]`.   This has a value of `'F'`.

Comment: Hi Peter. Just a small follow up question on y[][3]. When I tried to print "printf("\ny[2]: %s", y[2]);" then it resulted in output: "y[2]:G" which is totally fine. But when I tried to print " "printf("\ny[1][3]: %s", y[1][3]);" then it resulted in output "y[1][3]:G" which is very weird. Why is it showing output as G ? Is it because it will go to the next address of y[1] [2] which is y[2] ?

Comment: There are actually two problems in what you're doing.   Firstly, `y[1][3]` has type `char`, so printing it using `%s` gives undefined behaviour (type mismatch) - which means, technically, any consequence is possible.  You should actually use the `%c` format specifier.   Second, the fact that the second index has valid values between `0` and `2` inclusive is also problematic - but, since array elements are contiguous, `y[1][3]` will have the same value as `y[2][0]` - which is `'G'`.   You're getting lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you look at it) if it is actually printing `G`.

Comment: Ok. Got it. With C++ Visuals it is printing G. Thanks Peter for clarification. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do this

```
int z[][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
printf("\n**(z+1): %d", **(z + 1));
```

you actually get

```
int z[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
printf("\n**(z+1): %d", **(z + 1));
```

With this definition, `*(z+1)` points to `{4,5,6}` and therefore `**(z+1)` accesses the integer value `4`.
You access the first element of the second element of our array.

In your second version this happens:

```
char y[][3] = { "A", "F", "G", "J", "M", "P" };
printf("\n**(y+1): %c", **(y+1));
```

This will result in

```
char y[6][3] = { {'A',0,0}, {'F',0,0}, {'G',0,0}, {'J',0,0}, {'M',0,0}, {P',0,0}};
printf("\n**(y+1): %c", **(y+1));
```

Now `*(y+1)` points to `{'F',0,0}` and therefore `**(y+1)` accesses the character value `'F'`.
You access the first element of the second element of our array.

This is in fact the same result as with first version.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need two dimensional char array , if you use only one character in each array.

Like here:

```
char y[] = { 'A', 'F', 'G', 'J', 'M', 'P' };
printf("\n**(y+1): %c", *(y + 1));
```