# Is it standard-compliant to initialize a 2D array of unkown size by an 1D array initializer?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, language-lawyer

I recently came around [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495737/initialize-2d-array-with-1d-initializer-difference-between-int-and-char-when-de#comment110524587_62495737) where we got a 2D array definition like this one:

```
int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

The first dimension is empty/size of the array is unknown. The array `z` is initialized by a 1D array initializer.

Now, this is what the C standard says (emphasize mine):

> "If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching rightbrace initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the contained union. **Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part**.

Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.7.9/20.

This means it is well-defined to initialize a 2D array of known amount of elements with a 1D array initializer.

Thus, f.e.:

```
int y[2][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

should be equivalent to:

```
int y[2][3] = { { 0, 1, 2 } , { 3, 4, 5 } };
```

---

What I am worry about is this:

> "If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined *by the largest indexed element with an **explicit** initializer*. The array type is completed at the end of its initializer list."

Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.7.9/22.

It means that if the size of the array/ the amounts of elements within it is unknown, it requires that the 2D array:

1. Needs to have an largest indexed element, and
2. This element needs to have an explicit initializer.

---

My questions:

- Is that provided here?
- Is it standard-compliant to initialize a two-dimensional array of unkown size by an one-dimensional array initializer?

IMHO and after my actual stand of knowledge, it shouldn't. But maybe I misunderstand something here.

---

I opened this question because the other question is tagged with C and C++, so it is not real language lawyer appropriate and not focuses on C, plus the question of other question is actually quite different.

Comment: Your first example at the top has a `sizeof` 24. If I provide (MSVC) only 4 initilisers as in `int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };` the size is still 24. This seems to agree with your quote, as *the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer* in the "vertical" direction is (again) `x[1]`.

Comment: ...isn't it just expressing in a formal way that the outer dimension will be enough to hold all the explicitly initialized elements, and no more (unless defined)?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not quite sure if I can follow your comments. Why do both `int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };` and `int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` result in `sizeof(x) = 24` (at MSVC) in the first place? And how is that behavior defined? - I'm currently drawing blanks... :-/

Comment: Because they both need two "rows" when the row length has been defined as `3`. If you added one more initialiser to your example it would need one more "row" (with one explicitly defined value). I don't see how this is any different from a 1D array: the array will large enough to contain the initialized data, and no larger. In this case it would be equivalent to `int y[3][3] = { { 0, 1, 2 } , { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6 }};`

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay, I understand. That seems plausible, now. Thank you. So far so good. But how does that exactly relate to the quote "*its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its initializer list.*" - I still have problems in understanding that quote and the relation of this quote to what you told me.

Comment: Rephrasing it to *"the largest index of any initialised element..."*

Comment: @WeatherVane (Wrong example rewrote this comment) That confuses me back again. Now I think of something like `int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; ` == `int x[3][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };`. I have problems to identify what is what here. Note: I'm still awarding answers.

Comment: It's clear what is meant, even if maybe the language is not mathematically precise

Comment: @M.M It's clear what its meant if you know what it means. If you don't know what "*largest indexed element*" and "*explicit initializer*" means you have trouble. The standard missed to explain these terms explicitly which leaves room for ambiguity and I felt into the trap. It's not my fault. Maybe I have problems to understand, but the standard could have done better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per C 2018 6.7.9 20:

- `x` of `int x[][3]` is being initialized. It contains an element that is an aggregate, `x[0]`, which is an `int [3]`.
- The first initializer for this subaggregate is `0`. It does not begin with a brace. So “only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate…”. Thus three initializers, `0`, `1`, and `2`, are taken to initialize `x[0]`.
- Then “any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next element…”. So `4` and `5` are left to initialize `x[1]`.
- Again, `4` does not begin with a brace, so `4` and `5` are taken to initialize `x[1]`. Per paragraph 21, since there are not enough initializers to initialize `x[1]`, “the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.”

`4` and `5` are explicit initializers. They initialize `x[1]`. Therefore, `x[1]` has an explicit initializer. It is the largest indexed element of `x` that has an explicit initializer. Therefore it determines the size of `x`.

Comment: Can `x[1][0]` be seen in this context as "the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer" of `x`? I know that it is UB to use `x[3]` for example, but what I'm pointing at is different. If `x[1][0]` wouldn't be "*"the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer"*" the 2D array case would not match the quote and thus we would have undefined or at least unspecified behavior.

Comment: “If x[1][0] wouldn't be ""the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer""” is a subjunctive clause that is not relevant. `4` and `5` are explicit initializers. `x[1]` has these initializers. The fact that they are initializers only for part of `x[1]` is irrelevant, because it does not alter the fact that `x[1]` does in fact have these initializers. Therefore `x[1]` has explicit initializers. It is the largest-indexed element of `x` to do so, and therefore it determines the size of `x`.

Comment: Re “Can x[1][0] be seen in this context as "the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer" of x?”: No, because `x[1][0]` is not an element of `x`. `x[1]` is an element of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about this sentence from ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.7.9/22.

> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its initializer list.

Consider this definition

```
int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

The width is defined, so the compiler will initialise elements like this

```
x[0][0] = 0;
x[0][1] = 1;
x[0][2] = 2;
x[1][0] = 3;
```

This is from the **explicit** initialisation values defined. So now

- The highest inner index is `2`
- The highest outer index is `1`

So "the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer" is

```
x[0][2] = 2;    // "horizontally"
x[1][0] = 3;    // "vertically"
```

and the compiler creates the array

```
int x[2][3];
```

with the reminder of the last row implicitly initialised to `0`.

Comment: Isn't the "largest indexed element with an explicit initializer" only `x[1][0] = 3`?

Comment: No, that is the largest **initializer** or **value**. The standard says the largest **indexed element**.

Comment: In the case of the first subaggregate `x[0]`, the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer is `x[0][2]` indeed, but not for `x` itself. In context of the 2D array with its initializer list, `x[1][0]` should be the largest indexed element with an explicit element. If it wouldn't be in this way, the quote would not match the example, and we indeed would have undefined or unspecified behavior initializing the array `x` that way.

Comment: In what way isn't that what my answer says? `x[1][0]` is the element with the largest index in the outer dimension. For the inner dimension, that is *defined* otherwise the 2D array could not be constructed.

Comment: Your answer contains the part - "*So the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer is `x[0][2]` .... and `x[1][0]`*". Actual two "*largest indexed element with an explicit initializer*".

Comment: It is a 2D array. I gave the largest index in each dimension. I really don't know where you are going with this, or what is unclear to you.

Comment: You suggesting "two largest indexed elements with an explicit initializer", the quote state only "*the*" one. It's a difference.

Comment: That is because one is defined, and I was perhaps unneccessarily posting what should be obvious.

Comment: Don't take it personal. And no, I appreciate **every** answer. But look back at the facts. The standard only describes one regardless of whether it is an 1D or 2D array. Your answer is very well, but at this part it just contradicts or is at least not confirm to the standard. You helped me very much already but I just want to find the whole entire truth.

Comment: Well, you pointed out what you think is a contradiction, and (in comments) I pointed out that you are misreading it. "The largest" refers to the "largest element index" and not to the "largest element data". The *value* of the data is neither mentioned nor relevant.

Comment: Well OK, I understand now that you meant it well by illustrating both the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer at subaggregate (horizontal) and aggregate (vertical) level, but it just brought some more confusion of mine at that moment of time. Technically `x[1]` is the "l.i.e.w.a.e.i.", not `x[1][0]`. The focus of both horizontal and vertical elements with my concerns on this specific term made me mad.

Comment: The horizontal (innner) size was defined. As Eric mentioned, the largest index of `x` is `x[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

As you quoted from [6.7.9 Initialization](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p20):

> [..]  any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next
> element or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate
> or contained union is a part.

So

```
int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

equivalent to

```
int x[][3] = { { 0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5} };
```

i.e. after initializing the first element of the array with `{0, 1, 2}`, the rest of the initializers are forming the next element. And the *next element* being `int[3]` here.

Similarly,

```
int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

is equivalent to:

```
int x[][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6} };
```

and is equivalent to:

```
int x[3][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 0, 0} };
```

i.e.  [all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19).

Comment: I would like to use a new "Thank you" reaction (but I'm not a fan of this feature), because I appreciate your effort but I don't see or understand how this does address my concerns. My problem has emphasis on the quote "*If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its initializer list."*" and how does that apply to the provided example that it is standard-compliant to do so.

Comment: This answer seems to show clearly (last example) that because the final element with an explicit initialiser is `x[2][0]` the dimension will be `2 + 1 = 3`. No less, because that will overflow the array, and no more, because another row is not needed to hold the initialised data. This is the *highest index needed to hold explicitly initialised data.*

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio As quoted, each of the further initializer elements form a part of the *next* element. Thus `int x[][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` is equivalent to `int x[2][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` and the "highest indexed element" is 2 here.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio For the two arrays, the `sizeof` shows 24 & 36 as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/VcHN3U

Comment: @usr Yes, the 24 & 36 was a confusion. Didn't mind the added `6`.

Comment: @usr But how has the initializer `2` as "*largest indexed element*" in the first row an influence upon the amount of values in the array dimension of the 2D array `x`? Following the quote "*its size (array dimension) is determined by the largest indexed element (row) with an explicit initializer*"

Comment: @usr To clearly speaking. I understand now your examples in the answer, but not the quote.

Comment: To determine the 2nd dimension, the initializer list is used. Since each element is `int[3]`, each of the 3 numbers form "one" element for the 2nd dimension - total 2 for `int x[][3] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`. That's what the quote implies and I tried to explain in the 1st part of the answer.

Comment: @RobertS the "initializer with an influence" isn't in the first row, but in the *last row*. By definition, the last row used determines the array size in that direction. I can't see at all what you are having difficulty with. The higest index used horizontally is `[2]` (that was specified anyway) and the highest index vertically is also `[2]` (in the last example). So the array becomes `x[3][3]`. In the first example, the higest row index needed by initialized data is row 1. So that becomes `y[2][3]`.

Comment: My question is builded up on pedantry.  My mindset is the following: The quote says that the size of an array would be determined by the largest indexed element with an **explicit** initializer. But there is no **explicit** indexed element with an explicit initializer in the initializer list. The array is folded to build of 2/3 elements of type `int [3]` by compiler however, but it is not explicitly initialized to do so...

Comment: Thus, `int x[][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, { 3, 4, 5}, {6} };` would IMHO be standard-compliant, but not `int x[][3] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};` because there is no explicit initializer for the element of type `int[3]` part. I hope it now comes clearer where I'm pointing at. It is the rules themselves saying it needs an explicit initializer for the largest element.

Comment: Excuse me, it says the **initializer** which is explicit, not the index. The index progresses as needed. As you know, when the index is explicitly given, such as in `int x[2][3]` the data must fit. This is about when the index *isn't* explictily given, and so it can't be *both*.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is the confusion of where my question is build up. I want(ed) to have an explanation of the quote, but I don't find that in the answer, yet, to be honest. I understand now that the amount of elements (actually sub-aggregates) of the 2D array is determined by the amount of `int` values in the initializer list - the explicit initializer is of type `int`, not `int [3]` as I thought it would need to be, but the answer itself is missing to explain **that** explicitly - ...

Comment: In the question I showed that this quote is what I'm having trouble with and if it thus is standard-compliant to initialize a 2D array that way, but the answer is not focusing on the quote and that issue itself. Instead it shows me how it is evaluated. The answer is focusing on the *effect*, but not the my original *issuing* problem in the understanding of the quote.